# RaycastHit2D on NPC interfering with OnMouseUp() and OnMouseDown() in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, raycasting, onmouseup

I am creating a top-down 2D game in Unity with C#. I am trying to implement a wall-detection system using short 2D raycasts from my NPCs in order to avoid walls and avoid getting cornered.

I've attached 2D ray casters to my NPC prefab, and the required camera, but now I am unable to select my NPCs (okay they're not really NPCs, you select the one you want to control and that becomes the player temporarily until you lift the mouse). The selection is done through OnMouseUp() and OnMouseDown()

Here is my agent "My" class which contains both the FixedUpdate (containing the raycast code) and my OnMouseUp() and OnMouseDown() functions.

The my.physical.body is the GameObject's RigidBody2D
The "the" class is just a utility class which holds all my global variables and functions.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class My : Agent {
    // self
    public int index;
    public TextMesh label;
    public CircleCollider2D edge;
    public Physical physical;
    public Mind mind;
    public Structure structure;
    public Wall wall;
    public Square square;
    public List<WayPoint> path;
    public List<My> willAccept;
    // others
    public My target;
    public List<My> targetters;
    public List<Relationship> relationships;
    public List<Relationship> attention;
    public float vicinity;
    public float personalSpace;
    public float speed;
    public float speedLimit;
    public float time;
    public Vector2 restPosition;
    public Vector2 origin;
    public Vector2 gridPos;
    // Type
    public enum Type { Neut, Tadpole };
    public Type type;
    public Tadpole tadpole;
    public Neut neut;

    void Awake () {
        the = FindObjectOfType<The> ();
        my = this;
        origin = transform.position;
        physical.goal = transform.position;
        time = the.thinkOffset;
        the.thinkOffset += 0.1f;

        switch (my.type) {
        case My.Type.Tadpole: tadpole.enabled = true; break;
        default : neut.enabled = true; break; }
    }

    void Start() {
        label.text = name;
    }

    void Update() {

        if (the.player.my == my) {
            my.physical.goal = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
        } else if (my.target) {
            my.physical.goal = my.target.transform.position;
        }

        time -= Time.deltaTime;
        if ( time < 0 ) {
            time = 1f;
            my.physical.action.UpdatePath ();
        }

        wall.end.transform.position = physical.goal;
        physical.body.AddForce (physical.pathGoal);
        physical.skin.SetColor (emotional.state);
    }

    void FixedUpdate() {
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (transform.position, Vector2.down, 2);
        if (hit.collider != null) {
            print ("Raycast Hit at " + hit.point);
            float distance = Mathf.Abs (hit.point.y - transform.position.y);
            float difference = 2 - distance;
            float force = difference - my.physical.body.velocity.y;
            my.physical.body.AddForce (Vector3.up * force);
        }
    }

    public int power {
        get {
            return emotional.balance < 0 ? -emotional.balance : emotional.balance;
        }
    }

    void OnMouseUp() {
        the.player.my.physical.biases.Clear ();
        Vector2 mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);

        Bias bias = new Bias(mousePosition, 120);
        the.player.my.physical.biases.Clear ();
        the.player.my.physical.biases.Add (bias);
        the.player.my.physical.action.Untarget ();

        foreach (My target in the.agents.GetComponentsInChildren<My>()) {

            float distanceFromMouse = the.Distance (target.transform.position, mousePosition);

            if (distanceFromMouse < 1f) { 
                if (the.player.my) { 
                    the.player.my.physical.action.Target (target);
                    the.player.my.physical.biases.Clear ();
                }
            }
        }
        the.player.my = null;
        the.player.transform.parent = the.world.transform;
    }

    void OnMouseDown() {                                            

        float distanceFromPointer = the.Distance (this.transform.position, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition));

        if (distanceFromPointer < 1f) { 
            the.player.my = my;
            the.player.transform.parent = transform;
            the.cameraFocus = my.gameObject;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks,
James

Here are the other classes required for the code to compile

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Grammar : MonoBehaviour {

    public The the;
}
```

The class...

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class The : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject world;
    public Grid grid;
    public PathFinder pathFinder;
    public Intersections intersections;
    public GameObject cameraFocus;
    public float thinkOffset = 0.05f;

    public Structure border;
    public Structure map;

    public Player player;

    public GameObject squareParent;
    public GameObject linkParent;
    public GameObject nodeParent;
    public GameObject agents;

    public List<WayPoint> wayPoints = new List<WayPoint>();

    public int numberOfLines;

    public Color red;
    public Color yellow;
    public Color blue;
    public Color orange;
    public Color green;
    public Color purple;
    public Color gray;
    public Color darkGray;
    public Color black;
    public Color white;

    public Vector2 HeadingFrom(float angle) { return new Vector2(Mathf.Cos(angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad), Mathf.Sin(angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad)); }
    public float AngleFrom(Vector2 heading) { return Mathf.Atan2 (heading.y, heading.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg; }
    public Vector2 RelativeHeadingFrom(Vector2 heading, float rotation) { return (Vector2)(HeadingFrom(AngleFrom(heading) - rotation)); }
    public float Distance(Vector2 from, Vector2 to) { return (Heading(from,to)).magnitude; }
    public Vector2 Heading (Vector2 from, Vector2 to) { return to - from; }
    public Vector2 MidPoint (Vector2 from, Vector2 to) { return (from + to) / 2; }
    public Vector2 Product(Vector2 a, Vector2 b) { return new Vector2 (a.x * b.x, a.y * b.y); }
    public Vector2 Product(Vector2 a, float f) { return new Vector2 (a.x * f, a.y * f); }
}
```

Physical class

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Physical : Need {

    public Skin skin;
    public Action action;
    public Rigidbody2D body;
    public int size;
    public List<My> personalSpace;
    public Vector2 pathGoal;

    public void Awake() {
        goal = my.transform.position;
    }

    public void Start() {
        the = my.the;
        a = my.a;

        biases = new List<Bias> ();
        action = GetComponent<Action>();
        body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    }
}

Agent class

sing System.Collections;

public class Player : Agent {

    void Start () {
        a = FindObjectOfType<A> ();
        the = FindObjectOfType<The> ();
    }

    void Update () {
    }


}
```

Comment: I can almost guarantee you do not need all of those variables, considering you almost have more of them than other lines of code...

Comment: Good call, my variables definitely need some pruning.

Comment: Code does not compile, update the code with working version.

Comment: Thanks @m.rogalski I've added a few custom classes so that you can probably get it to run (if you delete some references to other custom classes). But all of the classes are inter-connected in some way, so I'm afraid I can't provide completely compilable code, barring posting the entire project. My question is more to do with conflicting rayCasts, the main camera raycaster (used for OnMouseDown()) and the new camera and raycaster I've attached to the NPCs.